Arabic text not displayed using Aframe
I'm trying to display Arabic text in A-Frame using the following code:
html
Copy code
<a-entity text="value: مرحباً بالعالم;"></a-entity>

However, instead of the expected Arabic text, I'm seeing a blank page. I've used the same method for English text, and it works fine. Why is this happening, and what do I need to do to properly render Arabic text in A-Frame? Do I need to configure something for right-to-left text or font support?
